# RoR development-environment setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment

I'm interested to play around with RoR a bit. Apart from literature i should read, i'm particularly interested about how to setup development environment.

Here's a good example how to setup environment [for Java](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/wiki/SettingUpJodaTimeForCSharpDevelopers) from Noda Time project wiki pages.
I want something similar but for RoR.

As far as i know - unix operation systems fits way much better (have toyed on windows 1 1/2 year ago - pure nightmare). So it would be nice to get some recommendations about linux distros and how to make it run next to win7/xp.

Basically - i want to shorten endless searching and improvisation until i can play with some code.

P.s. bonus for simple sample project. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The single quickest way to get up and running might be to simply grab [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) and develop against its built-in JRuby instance. It will walk you through setting up a Rails project and even give you some nice-to-haves like autocompletion.

Baring that, the easiest method is likely to download a Linux [VM Appliance pre-Customized for Rails Development](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/cat/0?k=rails&c=0) and a copy of VMWare Player.

Comment: I completely forgot about virtual machines. Thanks.

Comment: Virtual machines == less headaches.

Comment: I'm one of those performance freaks. That's why i usually don't use virtualization despite of occasional complete re-installations (and other problems...). But for educational purposes this is just perfect.

Comment: I agree with using NetBeans. It makes Rails development quite enjoyable.

Answer (score 1):

The best 2 ways to go are OS X and Linux, I use Ubuntu just because it's the nicest package that I've found (there will no doubt be a variety of opinons on this.)

For Rails, I like to not use the packages or pre-installed versions, and instead build my own so I can test against various versions of ruby if need be. [Hivelogic](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard/) has a nice post about how to do it for OS X 10.6.

From there, you can just run:

```
rails myproject
cd myproject
./script/generate scaffold post title:string body:text
rake db:migrate
rm public/index.html
./script/server --debugging
```

And then connect to http://localhost:3000/posts to get to your application.

Once you get more comfortable, check out running [Passenger](http://modrails.com/) instead, so you can have multiple applications running at the same time. On OSX there's even a nice [Prefpane](http://www.fngtps.com/passenger-preference-pane) to easily set up new sites. This also ins't too hard in Ubuntu with the examples provided in the passenger docs.

For editing the application I think the IDEs (Aptana, Netbeans, etc.) are still too heavyweight, especially for small starter projects. I like Textmate (like everyone else) for OSX and gedit with [gedit-mate](http://github.com/ivyl/gedit-mate).

Once you're writing applications, you'll find that [railsapi](http://railsapi.com) has the best interface for browsing all of the various methods not only in Rails, but ruby, authlogic, and a bunch of other common gems.

Lastly, you'll want to look into source control, with [git](http://git-scm.com/) being preferred in the Rails community at the moment.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> - Get VMWare player
> - Get ubuntu vm
> - If it's server version - install desktop x or whatever it's called
> - Mess around with sudos, visudos
> - Mess around with vi editor to save newly created account to sudoers list
> - Mess around with vertical mouse scrolling which apparently does not
>     work on vmware+ubuntu
> - Finally install netbeans
> - Through plugins, install ruby on rails
> - Some global updating
> - Enjoy toying
>
> tadaaaa...

Something like that i wanted - with each point explained a bit (no doubt that my steps aren't best ones and sounds funny for those who knows).

I guess that i forgot to mention that i lack knowledge of unix systems in general too.

Anyway - got what i was looking for. :)